# @Input does not work with OnPush change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, angular-changedetection

page.html

```
<app-parcel-delivery-cost-promo [parcelDeliveryCost]="parcelDeliveryCost">
  </app-parcel-delivery-cost-promo>
```

page.ts

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

parcelDeliveryCost: Partial<ParcelDeliveryCostModel>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.translateService.get(['Client.Parcel-Delivery-Cost']).subscribe(res => {

      this.parcelDeliveryCost = {
        title: res['Client.Parcel-Delivery-Cost'],
        description: res['Client.Parcel-Picked-Up-From-The-Location-And-Delivered-To-You'],
        cost: environment.parcelDeliveryCost
      };
    });
  }
```

component.ts

```
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

export class ParcelDeliveryCostPromoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() parcelDeliveryCost: ParcelDeliveryCostModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

}
```

componet.html

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" >
      <h5 class="font-bold margin-top-bottom-5">{{parcelDeliveryCost?.title}}</h5>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="12">
      <div class="color-medium">{{parcelDeliveryCost?.description}}</div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="12">
      <h4 class="margin-top-bottom-5 text-line-through">{{parcelDeliveryCost?.cost}}</h4>
    </ion-col>

  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Q: Could you tell me why `@Input` does not work with `OnPush` change detection? Where is the issue of this code? i.e. I can't see the `app-parcel-delivery-cost-promo` component. But if I'll change something on the page then it shows.

Answer (score 2):

Input works fine. Subscription in `ngOnInit` with `OnPush` doesn't run change detection. You need to do one of following:

- run change detector manually in subscription
- use `async` pipe instead of `.subscribe()` (async pipe runs `markForCheck`)
- turn off `OnPush` strategy

Comment: I have removed that sub and put it like so. But still, it is not working. Any clue? `this.parcelDeliveryCost = {
      title: 'Parcel-Delivery-Cost',
      description: 'Parcel-Picked-Up-From-The-Location-And-Delivered-To-You',
      cost: environment.parcelDeliveryCost,
      promoCost: environment.parcelDeliveryCostPromo,
      promoText: 'Promo',
    };`

Comment: Above code won'r run change detection as well. If you want to "test" if input works fine, define `this.parcelDeliveryCost` outside `ngOnInit`. Fill the value during variable definition.

You can also inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and run `detectChanges()` (with subscription or without subscription) after variable value assignment.

Comment: Why it is not working because I have created a new reference for this no `parcelDeliveryCost`? I don't like a manual way. Any reason why reference change not working here?

Comment: If you don’t like the ‘manual way’ why do you want to use onPush..? Doesn’t make sense..

Comment: @MikeOne It must have a natural way to do that. e.g. `async` pipe and more. That is why I don't like that ugly hack. I would like to know how to use the `async` pipe here on my use case.

Comment: Do not subscribe in the component but just assign the http Observable to a local var. Pass that observable to the input of the child with an async pipe.

Comment: Or don’t use onPush and let Angular change detection sort it out..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 this.parcelDeliveryCost = Object.assign({},{
        title: res['Client.Parcel-Delivery-Cost'],
        description: res['Client.Parcel-Picked-Up-From-The-Location-And-Delivered-To-You'],
        cost: environment.parcelDeliveryCost
      });
```

As if the reference of a object is updated angular will run change detection.